# Direct sum decomposition of $l_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $X=(V,E)$ be a finite graph and a linear operator $\nabla: l_2(V) \to l_2(E)$ given by the formula

$(\nabla f)(x,y)=$
\begin{cases}
f(x)-f(y) &d(x,y)=1\\
0         &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

> Then why can $l_2(V)$ be represented as a direct sum of ${l_2}^0(V)=\{f:V→\mathbb{R}|\sum_{x\in V}f(x)\}$ and $C = \{f:V→\mathbb{R}|f:\text{constant}\}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside: saying that $\nabla $ takes values in $l_2(E)$ is somewhat misleading unless you mean $E$ to be an **oriented** graph. And even then, your formula defines it on $V\times V$, not just on $E$.

More to the point, I see no relation between your question and the map $\nabla$. Your definition of $l_2^0$ is incomplete: should have been
$$l_2^0(V)=\left\{f:V→\mathbb{R}\,\bigg|\,\sum_{x\in V}f(x)=0\right\}$$
To check the claim about the direct sum, observe that:

1. Every  function in $l_2^0(V)$ is orthogonal to every constant function.
2. Given a function $f\in  l_2(V)$, one can consider $g=f-\mu$ where $ \mu$ is the average of $f$. Then $g \in l_2^0(V)$, and since $f=g+\mu$, we conclude that $l_2(V)$ is the orthogonal sum of two aforementioned subspaces.